# Changing Wordpress page link to be dynamic

Tags: wordpress

I have a page in wordpress that shows a template page, this page loads different content based on the id, here's the link i have now `www.whatever.com/mypage?id=123` so based on the id, I load my different content, when i edit the page, the permalink is `mypage`

What i need is changing `www.whatever.com/mypage?id=123` to be `www.whatever.com/mypage/123` , how can I achieve that?

NOTE: the `id 123` is a custom post type id, it's not a page id nor a post id, I want it to be generic as much as possible to add basically anything i need in

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Wordpress Dashboard - Settings - Permalinks
and you can rewrite the Permalinks